# acronyms glossary: How can I fix the vertical alignment between the notation and description columns?

Tags: glossaries

I'm having some trouble displaying my glossaries. I import the glossaries package as follows:

```
\usepackage[%
  automake,
  xindy
  section = section,
  nonumberlist,
  sanitize={symbol=false},
  shortcuts,
  acronym,
  nomain,%
  nowarn%
]{glossaries}
```

My glossary style looks like this:

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
  \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
  \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
  \newglossarystyle{my_style}{%
    %\glossarystyle{super3colheader}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}{L{0.15\textwidth}L{0.8\textwidth}R{0\textwidth}}}%
    {\end{longtable}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{\bf{\entryname} & \bf{\descriptionname} & \\} % table header
    %\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3 \\} % table body
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{% 
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}
        \tabularnewline
    }%
  }
```

However, when I use printglossary to display the abbreviations, there is a height difference for some rows between the notation and the description (view image below). How can I make sure that entries in both columns are aligned?

[image: The displayed glossary entries]

A minimal example producing a list of misaligned entries in the glossary:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

% DEFAULT PACKAGES
\usepackage[
  main=english,%                        % primary language
  ngerman%                              % secondary language
]{babel}                                % language options (primary: english, secondary: german)

\usepackage{graphicx}                      % fix figures (float environment)
\usepackage{tikz}                       % tikz graphics
\usepackage{mathtools}                  % erweiterte Fassung von amsmath
\usepackage{amssymb}                    % erweiterter Zeichensatz
\usepackage{siunitx}                    % Einheiten
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % mathematical formulars
\usepackage{amsthm}                     % definition of custom theorems and definitions
\usepackage[%
  automake,
  xindy,%                               % use xindy for makeglossaries
  section = section,%                   % use sections for all glossary lists 
  nonumberlist,%                        % no page references in lists
  sanitize={symbol=false},%             % do not dissect symbols
  shortcuts,%                           % make use of shorthand notation
  acronym,%                             % acronym glossary
  %nopostdot,%                           % remove the point at the end
  %nogroupskip,%                         % don't skip any groups
  nomain,%                              % do not generate main glossary
  nowarn%                               % suppress warnings
]{glossaries}                           % glossary (abbreviations and symbols)
%\usepackage[]{glossaries}[=v4.49] 
\usepackage{tabularx}                   % table environment used for IAS glossary style
\usepackage{booktabs}                   % Verbesserte Möglichkeiten für Tabellenlayout über horizontale Linien
\usepackage{longtable}                  % table environment used for IAS glossary style
\usepackage{enumitem}                   % less space between vertical items in enumerate
%\usepackage{listings}                   % listings, e.g. for matlab code in the appendix
\usepackage{xcolor}                     % coloring of listings
\usepackage{caption}                    % enumerated captions in figures, etc.
\usepackage{subcaption}                 % subcaptions for subfigures
\usepackage{epstopdf}                   % include eps graphics
% \usepackage{psfrag}                     % modify eps graphics (does not work with matlab eps files)
\usepackage{wrapfig}                    % wraps text around figures
\usepackage[%
  vlined,%                              % design of code blocks
  boxed%                                % layout of the algorithm
]{algorithm2e}                          % algorithm environment

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}        % Anführungszeichen vereinfacht
\usepackage{microtype}

%%--------------------
% DEBUG PACKAGES
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{todonotes}

%%--------------------
% USE CUSTOM STYLE
\usepackage{style}


\newacronym{iid}{i.i.d.}{independently and identically distributed} % missing
\newacronym[\glslongpluralkey={Markov Decision Processes}]{MDP}{MDP}{Markov Decision Process}
\newacronym[\glsshortpluralkey={KL}]{KL}{KL}{Kullback-Leibler divergence} % missing
\newacronym{DL}{DL}{Deep Learning}
\newacronym{ML}{ML}{Machine Learning}
\newacronym{RL}{RL}{Reinforcement Learning} % misaligned
\newacronym{NAS}{NAS}{Neural Architecture Search} % misaligned
\newacronym[plural=GFlowNets]{gflownet}{GFlowNet}{Generative Flow Network}
\newacronym{gflownas}{GFlowNAS}{GFlowNAS}
\newacronym{DAG}{DAG}{Directed Acyclic Graph} % misaligned
\newacronym{SGD}{SGD}{Simple Gradient Descent} % misaligned
\newacronym{MCMC}{MCMC}{Markov Chain Monte Carlo} % misaligned
\newacronym[plural=VAEs, firstplural=Variational Autoencoders]{VAE}{VAE}{Variational Autoencoder} % misaligned
\newacronym[plural=GANs, firstplural=Generative Adversarial Networks]{GAN}{GAN}{Generative Adversarial Network}
\newacronym[plural=GAFlowNets]{gaflownet}{GAFlowNet}{Generative Augmented Flow Network} % misaligned
\newacronym{TB}{TB}{Trajectory Balance} % misaligned
\newacronym{FM}{FM}{Flow Matching} % misaligned
\newacronym{DB}{DB}{Detailed Balance}
\newacronym{VI}{VI}{Variational Inference} % missing
\newacronym[plural=EBGFlowNets, firstplural=Energy Based GFlowNets]{ebgflownet}{EBGFlowNet}{Energy Based GFlowNet} % misaligned
\newacronym{MLE}{MLE}{Maximum Likelihood Estimation}
\newacronym[plural=MLPs, firstplural=Multi Layer Perceptrons]{MLP}{MLP}{Multi Layer Perceptron}
\newacronym{cifar10}{CIFAR-10}{CIFAR-10}
\newacronym[plural=GCNs, firstplural=Graph Convolutional Networks]{gcn}{GCN}{Graph Convolutional Network}
\newacronym{sota}{SOTA}{state-of-the-art} % missing
\newacronym{TD}{TD}{Temporal Difference}

%% CREATE GLOSSARY
\makeglossaries

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter*{Abbreviations,~Symbols and Operators}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=acronym,title=List of Abbreviations,style=my_style]

\section{Introduction}

Your introduction goes here! Simply start writing your document and use the Recompile button to view the updated PDF preview. Examples of commonly used commands and features are listed below, to help you get started.

Once you're familiar with the editor, you can find various project settings in the Overleaf menu, accessed via the button in the very top left of the editor.



%\bibliographystyle{alpha}
%\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

The corresponding style.sty file:

```
\newcommand{\mc}  [1]{\mathcal{#1}}     % shortcut for caligraphic math font
\newcommand{\ul}  [1]{\underline{#1}}   % shortcut for underline
\newcommand{\bs}     {\textbackslash}   % shortcut for printing a backslash
\newcommand{\bf}[1]{\textbf{#1}}      % shortcut for bold font
\newcommand{\it}[1]{\textit{#1}}      % shortcut for italic font

%% notation
\newcommand{\cvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\cmat}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{#1}}}

%% tabular options
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}       % global padding for tabulars

%% paragraph options
\parindent0pt                           % do not indent paragraphs

%% TOC options
% 0 → chapter, 1 → section, 2 → subsection, 3 → subsubsection
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}                % hide subsections and lower from TOC

%% glossary definition
% sources:  http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#x1-4700015
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newglossarystyle{my_style}{%
    %\glossarystyle{super3colheader}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}{L{0.15\textwidth}L{0.8\textwidth}R{0\textwidth}}}%
    {\end{longtable}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{\bf{\entryname} & \bf{\descriptionname} & \\} % table header
    %\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3 \\} % table body
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{% 
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}       %Name
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}          %Beschreibung
        %& \glossentrysymbol{##1}                   %Symbol (wird von mir als Unit verwendet)
        \tabularnewline                             %Ende
}%
}
```

Comment: As always here, please provide a full but minimal example others can just copy and test as is without having to add any code. Then you are much more likely to get help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. I guess the command \glossarystyle is deprecated. Simply adding the style=super3colheader argument to the glossary package import fixed the alignment problem.

```
\usepackage[%
  automake,
  xindy,%                               % use xindy for makeglossaries
  style=super3colheader,
  section = section,%                   % use sections for all glossary lists 
  nonumberlist,%                        % no page references in lists
  sanitize={symbol=false},%             % do not dissect symbols
  shortcuts,%                           % make use of shorthand notation
  acronym,%                             % acronym glossary
  %nopostdot,%                           % remove the point at the end
  %nogroupskip,%                         % don't skip any groups
  nomain,%                              % do not generate main glossary
  nowarn%                               % suppress warnings
]{glossaries}
```